# got 404 error while using getUserMedia() API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I have index.html and app.js -
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Realtime communication with WebRTC</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>
  <video autoplay></video>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js =>

```
'use strict';
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
var constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: true
};
var video = document.querySelector('video');

function successCallback(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // stream available to console
  if (window.URL) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  } else {
    video.src = stream;
  }
}
function errorCallback(error) {
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

So when I open run index.html
I got error - 
:8888/getUserMedia/[object%20MediaStream]:1 GET http://localhost:8888/getUserMedia/[object%20MediaStream] 
getUserMedia is not a function.

I also tried on apache server. But got same error.

Comment: Did some stupid things. My code is all fine and working properly. I added different js file. 
Sorry!

Answer (score 6):

include [adapter.js](https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js) and set
`video.srcObject = stream;`
Everything else is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You just change

```
element.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

to:

```
element.srcObject = stream;
element.onloadedmetadata = function(e) { element.play(); };
```

Comment: This is the correct Answer, Because element.src= stream;make error too